# azure pyspark from modules import myfunctions; No module name

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have tried a number of methods to import a local script containing an bunch of shared functions from our shared team directory with example in the code below.   I also tried "from . import sharedFunctions"  with the importing script in the same directory and "from sharedModules import sharedFunctions" from the parent directory.  All of these return No module named 'sharedFunctions' based on some google searches.   What is the best way to set this up in Azure?

Thanks

```
import sys, os
dir_path = '/Shared/XXX/sharedModules'
sys.path.insert(0, dir_path)
print(sys.path)
# dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# sys.path.insert(0, dir_path)
import sharedFunctions

sourceTable='dnb_raw'
sourceQuery='select DUNSNumber , GlobalUltimate_Name, BusinessName from'
sourceId = 'DUNSNumber'
sourceNameList=['Tradestyle','BusinessName']
NewTable = 'default.' + sourceTable + '_enhanced'  
#dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/" + NewTable + "/",recurse=True)
clean_names(sourceTable,sourceQuery,sourceId,sourceNameList)
```

Comment: I correctly understand that the code is in the notebooks?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to import another notebook.

Comment: pain in the ass, but databricks notebooks don't run like standard .py scripts, you need to import it into your file using `%run \path\to_your\dbc_file` my own work around is to create a package then import those, but it makes updates difficult if your team aren't up to date with devops / github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're working with notebooks in Databricks, they are not on some file system that is understood by Python as module.

If you want to include another notebook with some other definitions into the current context, you can use [%run magic command](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run), passing the name of another notebook as an argument:

```
%run /Shared/XXX/sharedModules/sharedFunctions
```

But the `%run` is not the full substitution for imports, as described in the documentation

> You cannot use %run to run a Python file and import the entities defined in that file into a notebook. To import from a Python file you must package the file into a Python library, create a Databricks library from that Python library, and install the library into the cluster you use to run your notebook.

If you want to execute another notebook to get some results from it, you can use so-called [notebook workflow](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html) - when exeucting via `dbutils.notebook.run`, the notebook is scheduled for execution, you can pass some parameters to it, etc., but results will be shared mostly via file system, managed table, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I also found a library that was created inpypi for this name libify.